# Why `@change` trigger don't work for v-data-picker?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use [v-calendar](https://vcalendar.netlify.com/) package in my Vue.js application.

I want to send selected data range values to parent component. Why `@change` trigger don't work?

**Parent.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Child @setRange="setRange" :range="range"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
data() {
    return {
        range: this.range,
    }
},
mounted() {
    firstCallToPage();
},
methods: {
    firstCallToPage(){
        axios.get('URL').then(response => {
            let self = this;
            this.range = {
                start: response.startDate,
                end: response.endDate,
            };
        }
    },
    setRange(range_value) {
        this.range = range_value;
    }
}
</script>
```

**Child.vue:**

```
<v-date-picker class='v-date-picker'
                       mode='range'
                       v-model='rangeValue'
                       :show-day-popover=false
                       :max-date='new Date()'
                       show-caps
                       :input-props='{placeholder: "", readonly: true}'
                       @change="sendRange">
</v-date-picker>
props: {
    range: {
        type: Object,
    },
},

data() {
  return {
    rangeValue: this.range
  }
},

sendRange: function () {
    this.$emit('setRange', this.rangeValue);
}
```

**ERROR** in console:

```
Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders.
Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "range"
```

Comment: I'm diving into the [docs](https://docs.vcalendar.io/api.html#date-picker-props) and they seem to use `@input` instead of `@change`. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thank you for information. I successfully send date range values to parent companent when user select date in widget. In fact the problem was with mutation. It steal show me this message. Can you check my post again pls. I add error message which I see in console. How I can fix it? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I provided you an answer.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek - Great! If it works for you and you are happy - then in general you would accept the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have. You can read about accepting here: stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty explicit. The problem is that you give a prop to your child component (the one that contains `v-date-picker`) and you are overriding this prop with `v-model` (`v-model` is just syntactic sugar for `:value` and `@change`).

Derive your prop's value with a `data` value and use it for your operations:

```js
<v-date-picker class='v-date-picker'
                       mode='range'
                       v-model='rangeValue'
                       :show-day-popover=false
                       :max-date='new Date()'
                       show-caps
                       :input-props='{placeholder: "", readonly: true}'
                       >
</v-date-picker>
props: {
    range: {
        type: Object,
    },
},

data() {
  return {
    rangeValue: this.range
  }
},

sendRange: function () {
    this.$emit('setRange', this.rangeValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use your code. In first call to the page `range` variable has values but `rangeValue` variable don't have any value. For thats why there is no data in `v-date-picker` widget. In the same time there is no message in console. Why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: I would need a CodeSandbox of your app or at least the code of your parent component to understand what's happening. Could you modify your original post and add one of them?

Comment: Check my post again please.

Comment: It's not working with :value, @change, date-picker is not triggering the change event. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

Try @input instead of @change. In v-datetime-picker works only with @input.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a method, you can make use of watch...

Consider you have the following attributes in the range Object

```js
range: {
   start:value,
   end: value
}
```

```js
<v-date-picker class='v-date-picker'
                       mode='range'
                       v-model='rangeValue'
                       :show-day-popover=false
                       :max-date='new Date()'
                       show-caps
                       :input-props='{placeholder: "", readonly: true}'
                       >
</v-date-picker>
props: {
    range: {
        type: Object,
    },
},
watch: {
  'rangeValue.start': function(newVal){
      this.$emit('setRange', newVal);
  }
},
data() {
  return {
    rangeValue: this.range
  }
}
```